# exporting a denormalized table to cassandra table with map and list columns

Tags: json, hadoop, cassandra

I have a denormalized table in mysql with a structure like this:

```
AcctID | fName | lName | userId | ProductCode | Street | City | State | Zip
```

A person can only have one userId but that person can have multiple AccIDs each with there own address. So in cassandra, I would create a table like this:

```
create type acctInfo (
  prodCode text,
  street text,
  city text,
  state text,
  zip int
);

create type fullName (
  fName text,
  lName text
 );

create table CustInfo (
  userId PRIMARY KEY,
  name fullName,
  accts map<text, frozen<acctInfo>>
);
```

I understand the nested structure in a csv file that I would need as in this example...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5590

I could write a shell script to generate the json array for each line in the csv file but it would run a lot of queries against my denormalzied table in mySql to create a csv file. Is there any other way to do this?

I could also export this denormalized table from mySql and drop it into HDFS as well.

I guess my question is, what is the best way to get a denormalized table from a relational database system into cassandra with maps and lists?

Comment: if you have spark-cluster then you can create one spark job. or you can install in one node for that migration.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to load all data into cassandra from mysql is through spark . you can get all data at one time and put into list and map then push data in cassandra .

Comment: So am I building the transformation logic using scala and spark is just running it? Doing some reading as I'm not really familiar with Spark...

Comment: so do I need to do data transformations using spark before I upload the data into Cassandra like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052831/formatting-a-spark-array-adding-string-to-element-and-using-brackets

Comment: yes you have to transform data according to your table then create rdd in push rdd into cassandra table